# Post pictures from Iphone

Tags: support

How do I post pictures on here to reference when asking a question? I do not see an upload prompt or anything of the sort and I do not know computer coding.

Comment: when you edit a question or post an answer the "upload picture" symbol is the 4th graphic in the second set on the edit bar.

Comment: Note that if it is a picture of a problem out of a textbook it will not be well received.

Answer (score 2):

> When you edit a question or post an answer the "upload picture" symbol is the 4th graphic in the second set on the edit bar. – [MaxW](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/users/22102/maxw) [Apr 24 at 6:27](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3209/post-pictures-from-iphone#comment3055_3209)